# Python - (if/else) extra characters?

Tags: python, if-statement

So I'm doing my homework but I can't seem to figure out how to add "extra" characters to regular statement.

I want this code to say that `lname` have to consist only from letters and `" "` or/and `"-"` symbols and can't start with `" "`. How can I achieve this? I don't even know what to search for or try. Isn't there some kind of “includes” function built in? I'm getting desperate.

```py
def perenimi2():
    global lname
    lname = perenimi.get()

    if lname.isalpha():
            textVar.set("")
            nd2 = {"Perenimi": str(lname)}
            uusklient.update(nd2)
            post2()
            
    else:
        textVar.set ("Sisestage korrektne perekonnanimi!")
```

What I mean is how can I make IF statement that MUST include letters and may also include "-" or/and space. I want to make fname to be only letters and "-" or/and space. (This is for a name field which also can't start with space)

I'm sorry if this has been asked before but I haven't been able to find the solution.

-----CODE AFTER USING POSTED ANSWER-----
With the posted answer I found a new problem, it now allows input or entry to be empty which can't be empty.

I translated everything to English.

```py
import string


###FirstName

def firstname1():
    global fname
    allowed = " -"
    cantStart = " "
    fname = firstname.get()
    
    if (set(fname) <= set(allowed + string.ascii_letters) and not fname.startswith(cantStart)):
        textVar.set("")
        familyname2()
    
    elif fname == "":
        textVar.set("Insert correct name!")

        
    else:
        textVar.set("Insert correct name!")
        
###FamilyName
def familyname2():
    global lname
    lname = familyname2.get()
    allowed = " -"
    cantStart = " "
    empty = ""
    
    if (set(lname) <= set(allowed + string.ascii_letters) and not lname.startswith(cantStart)):
        textVar.set("")
        post2()
        
    elif lname == "":
        textVar.set("Insert correct family name!")

    else:
        textVar.set("Insert correct family name!")


firstname1()
```

Comment: [Please don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can search for an exact problem at the top of this site, to the right of the Stack Overflow logo and "Products"

Comment: Welcomed to be here! I still can't find the solution from the forum, although I edited this post and explained my problem better. Maybe someone can help me.

Also removed the image and added my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import string

ALLOWED = " -"
CANT_START = " "

if (set(lname) <= set(ALLOWED + string.ascii_letters) 
        and not lname.startswith(CANT_START)
        and lname):
```

No `elif` branch (i.e. remove it from your code).

---

*The explanation:*

`string.ascii_letters` is `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"`

`set(lname)` is the set of all characters in `lname`, e. g. if `lname == "abba"`, then `set(lname)` will be `"ab"`.

The `<=` operation between two sets means “is a subset of”, i.e. if all elements in the left set exist in the right set, too.

`lname` is `True` only for *nonempty* strings (you may also use `lname != ""`, but using only `lname` is more Pythonic).

The long expression in the `if` branch is surrounded with parentheses only for the possibility to *split it freely into more lines,* i.e. without the necessity to end every non-complete line with the continuation symbol (`\`). Otherwise, it has to be in the form as

```
if set(lname) <= set(ALLOWED + string.ascii_letters) \
       and not lname.startswith(CANT_START)          \
       and lname:
```

(or be written fully only in one, very long line).

Comment: Thank you very much, @MarianD! It worked perfectly on my code! I probably wouldn't have come to this solution by myself. Now I just need to exercise and fully understand this. A BIG thank you for the explanation aswell!

Comment: @arx, you're welcome. Please consider *voting up* my answer (click the upper triangle next to it) on and/or *accepting it* (click the check mark) if it was helpful for you. Please see [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I don't have enoguh "reputation" to vote but I accepted the answer! Though I am now facing another problem, it now seems that my code also accepts empty answer which is also a problem. I tried elif fname == "" (empty string?):  but this didn't fix my problem. I'm going to add my code example to the original post. I feel like I need a break (overthinking or not thinking at all) to restart myself but the deadline is coming and I need to get this one done.

Comment: I edited my answer adding `and lname` to your `if` condition. Now it fulfills your extended condition.

Comment: Your `elif` branch didn't work because in my previous answer the condition in the `if` branch is fulfilled for empty string, too (`set(lname)` is empty in this case, and the empty set is subset of the every set). Use my current answer (no need for an `elif` branch).

Comment: You have an error in the statement `lname = familyname2.get()` — `familyname2` is the name of  your **function**, and you wanted probably use a name of your **control**  - probably with the name `familyname`. So correct it to `lname = familyname.get()`.

Comment: Thank you!! You probably saved me a lots of time and taught ( or introduced) me an important part of python. At the moment I'm struggling with email field, but i'll try to solve this by myself. I couldn't find that (lname = familyname2.get()) error in my original code, so I believe it came from translating. Thank you once again.